# Is there anywhere in the world an alternative to Cap d'Agde as a nudist resort?

Tags: nudism

The (in)famous Cap d'Agde is probably [the most renowned nudist village](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cap_d%27Agde) in Europe. There it is not only possible to roast your whole body in the sun, but you can actually go shopping naked, in fact it is allowed to be naked (almost) everywhere inside the resort.

[image: Would you look at his feet?! How dirty they are!]

Fun fact: the place is a swingers magnet. Needless to say, the place is expensive as hell.

Is there any place like that anywhere in the world? To qualify as "like that", I would like to know if another place exists where:

- Nudity is allowed
- Nudity is allowed (almost) anywhere inside the village
- The resort can be seasonal
- The resort is near or at a touristic location (seaside, mountians, city... just not lost in the land)
- The resort should be "village-sized", not just a camping
- BONUS (optional): swingers are allowed

Comment: I am sure there are dozens or even hundreds of nudist resorts that fit these criteria (except possibly that swingers are allowed). Can you narrow it down a bit?

Comment: Well, I did have only 1 answer, so I'm not betting on the "hundreds" :) Anyway, I'm curious about *big* resorts (I just edited the question)

Comment: Have you seen Wikipedia's [lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_places_where_social_nudity_is_practised)? The resorts are all mixed in with beaches and other places, but there are certainly many of them.

Comment: Yes (+1 btw), but none has a supermarket where you can go shopping bare :D Well nor does burning man, but the venue in that case is *huge*

Comment: @Noldor130884 there are others, but probably nothing on the scale of cap d'agde.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One venue to consider is [Burning Man](http://www.burningman.org), an annual festival in the Black Rock Desert in Nevada, USA. It is pretty remote, so it might qualify as "lost in the land", but it certainly fulfills most of your criteria.

Nudity is permitted and common at Burning Man (though far from obligatory). Crossdressing is also allowed, as is wearing bizarre costumes.

Comment: I think the "wearing bizarre costumes" is the coolest thing about the whole thing :D

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you call an alternative...

There are quite a few naturist camp grounds and resorts with (some) facilities, usually a small grocery store/supermarket, a swimming pool and/or sauna, and a restaurant/snackbar.

But I'm not aware of anything on the same scale.

In the Netherlands there's Flevonatuur near Zeewolde for example that has some bungalows and tents for rent as well as places to put down your own tent.

A specialist naturist tour operator (yes, they do exist) should be able to find something for you, and naturist organisations in general often have lists of facilities in their area of operation available.

But do remember that most naturist places don't want to have the swinger and free sex crowd that cap d'Agde is infamous for.